# Is this a standard cable? (USB Type A + unknown)

Tags: usb, connector, identification, cables

I have a cable that I cannot match with any device. My question is **whether this is a standard cable, or rather a proprietary invention**.

On one side there is a standard USB Type A male connector.

[image]

The other side is the one I cannot recognize. It looks like an electrical connector (230V, Europe, often used to connect some "mobile radios" (usually also powered by batteries)), such as this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZSez.jpg. It is smaller, enforces polarity, and is obviously not for 230V.

(the scale on the images below is in centimeters)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a Philips shaver USB charging cable. So it is a proprietary cable.

Comment: Do those have some sort of excessively clever power input circuit which can accept both 5 VDC and 220 VAC over the same two contacts?

Comment: @ChrisStratton no, nothing excessively clever. They use a wall wart, so there won't be 220 VAC anyway over that plug, but smaller isolated DC voltage.

Comment: It looks like there's a non-standard groove on this which would hopefully make it impossible to plug earlier earlier grooveless Phillips/Norelco **direct mains cords** into the DC input product.   But it's not clear what would prevent a standard double-groove mains cord from fitting.   Even a slight difference in spacing and different grooving seems very risky as someone may say "oh, I'll make that fit" and grab a pocket knife.   They really should have changed their case mouldings when they changed  input voltage; they change them now and then anyway for aesthetic design reasons.

Comment: You are correct however that overall it is smaller.  The picture seems to show 11 mm as the width, I measure 14mm for the older shave mains cord, and a standard mains cord is a bit wider still.   **It still makes me uncomfortable** and feels like they did a "lazy" change rather than a good one (and at the cost of having a likely custom connector made!)... Isn't there a European e-waste avoidance directive requiring USB charging cords to use standard connectors for interchangeability?  Not that those are the most robust thing for non-USB power applications anyway.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: the universal charger law (still in preparation) would be for mobile phone chargers. Other chargers are not impacted, unfortunately.

Comment: I found a Philips shaver and compared the plugs: https://imgur.com/ehile0k. It is not the same plug.